# is possible to send two order email with diffrent diffrent email template with magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise

Is it possible to send two order emails with different email templates?

If yes please let me know how we can solve this ?

or let me know if any extension will achieve this goal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461577/is-possible-to-send-two-email-in-magento-with-diffrent-diffrent-tempale-please-t/29472509#29472509

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite Mage_Sales_Model_Order module to add your custom logic to sendNewOrderEmail()
You could disable order emails (see Magento: send New Order Email only with cronjobs) create (eg checkout_submit_all_after) and do your own custom email sending